# Expirations of WTI options

Tags: market-data

Where can I find expiration dates of WTI options like this: http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_product_calendar_options.html

But I need dates in 2012-2016 years. 
Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the past expiry dates yourself.

From the [future contract specs](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_contract_specifications.html) you can see that the last trading day of the futures contracts is always three business days before the 25th calendar day of the month preceding the delivery month. If the 25th is not a business day itself, then the trading ceases three business days before the last business preceding the 25th.

From the [option contract specs](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude_contractSpecs_options.html) you can see that the last trading day of the options is three business days before that of the underlying futures contract.

Comment: Where can I find future contract info for 2012-2016?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. As I wrote in the answer - you can calculate both the past futures and option expiry dates yourself.

Comment: It's okay. I understand.